# Отправка PUSH NOTIFICATION и открытие ACTIVITY

Tags: android, android-studio, уведомления, fcm

Есть следующий код по отправке push уведомления:

```
private static final String channelId = "default_notification_channel_id";

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewPredl.class);
        intent.putExtra("dp", dp); 




        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) 
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setColor(Color.GRAY) 
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 1000)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notifz, notifiBuilder.build());
```

Хочется чтобы при отправке уведомления работали следующим образом:
Отправляю уведомление  открывается активити и туда передается  значения dp, Отправляю второе уведомление при нажатии открывается активити и туда передаются другие значения dp
Каждое уведомление разное и не затирает друг друга.

У меня на данный момент получается в уведомлении отображаются правильные значения, а при нажатии на уведомление  активити то не открывается то открывается только одно.

Какой флаг PendingIntent нужно установить? (установлен PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

Нужно ли каждый раз отправлять разные notifz или достаточно поставить 0?

channelId каждый раз нужен разный или можно постоянный?